# Hibernate Query Language (HQL) Update list

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sql-update, hql

I'm using Hibernate and I want to make a bulk update, changing the status of all objects within a list of ids.
So I tried:

```
String update = "UPDATE Foo as foo SET foo.status = :status WHERE foo.id in (:idList)"
```

Which caused an exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

I also tried:

```
String update = "UPDATE Foo as foo SET foo.status = :status WHERE foo.id in (SELECT id FROM Foo WHERE id in (:idList))"
```

That caused the same exception.

I'm inserting the parameters like this:

```
StatelessSession ss = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
Query query = ss.createQuery(update);
query.setParameter("status", status);
query.setParameterList("idList", ids);
query.executeUpdate();
```

Any ideas how to make this work?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove the Braves around the Parameter. They should be added by hibernate

Comment: I removed, but still got the same error :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Status`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) is a MySQL reserved word. Rename your column to something else

Comment: Is there any other way? I don't think I can easily change that

Comment: Surrounding the field with backticks is an option but longterm you'll need to add them everywhere so renaming is preferable...